# How do I make a SOAP PHP request with authetication and display the contents?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I'm trying to learn some SOAP and PHP, I have a link that is WSDL , it has a username and a password. How do I connect to the site with the authetication and display it;s contents on a php webpage ?

`$client = new SoapClient("site.php?wsdl");` 
How do I go about adding the user name, password and simply outputting the contents on a php webpage ?

Please assist

Comment: You want to display the raw WSDL contents, you mean? Or you want to get some data from the API which is descrbed by the WSDL? If so, what data? And what does "it has a username and password" mean exactly? You mean the WSDL requires authentication before you can download it? Show an example. It isn't 100% clear what the issue is.

Comment: Display the contents of the wsdl, connecting to it requires a user name and a password. www.dummyex.com/page.php?wsdl , need to displays its contents on a php webpage.

Comment: Ok you don't need soapclient for that then. soapclient is when you want to read the wsdl and generate API stubs from it, and then make a request to the actual API. If you simply want to download the wsdl itself, then use curl or file_get_contents to make a http requst to its URL, and via those you can specify the username/password as a header value in the normal way (assuming it's using standard HTTP basic authentication)

Comment: ```<?php

$username = "some-username";
$password = "some-password";
$remote_url = 'http://www.somedomain.com/path/to/file';

// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")                 
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents($remote_url, false, $context);

print($file);

?>``` Like This ? though this just presents an empty page

Comment: That looks like the general idea yes. I assume you substituted the correct URL. You'd have to check the response headers as well to see if the request returned any errors or anything. Also try `var_dump($file)` to see exactly if it's a null or false or something.

Comment: string(2017) " 

 " Thats all im getting in reply any idea why ? , The site is http://www.autobid.co.za/halfway/vehicledetails.php?wsdl

Comment: That URL doesn't need a password, I just went straight to it

Comment: Like I said though you need to retrieve the http headers and get the response code and/or any other errors